# How to learn core linux operations

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, fedora, opensuse

I found that there are lots of distributions(such as Arch Linux,CentOS,Manjaro,Mageia,Fedora,openSUSE,Ubuntu) based on linux kernel.

I wanted to know what basics do I have learn so that learning any distribution will not be a tough task for me.

Comment: I'd suggest you go for arch or gentoo. Yes they are diy distros and you will have to spend a ton of time configuring the system, but, in the end, it's much better than some packed up distro like ubuntu, fedora, or mint if you want to learn about 'linux', because you will have to unlearn a lot of things if you start with these readymade distros. What you get on a minimal diy distro is what is common among all the linux distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some helpful links:

[Linux Journey](https://linuxjourney.com/)

[Intro to Linux - Linux Foundation MOOC](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-0)

Comment: Thank you brother, would you help me how to figure out what are the new things the distributor had added to original kernel

Comment: @user313265 Each distribution is different.  You could compare the packages that are not the Linux kernel for each system.